# Got error in making imageview as stretchable when imageview is added as subview of uitableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, chat

I want to make imageview as stretchable if i write more then two lines in table cell. But i got problem as below :

My code for cell is as below:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   chatCell *cell = (chatCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CHAT_CELL_IDENTIFIER];
   NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
   if (row < chatData.count)
   {

    NSString *chatText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:TEXT];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    CGSize size = [chatText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(150.0f, 1000.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
    cell.textString.frame = CGRectMake(75, 18, size.width +20, size.height + 20); // set text frame
    cell.textString.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE];        // set text font
    cell.textString.text = chatText;                                              // set text
    [cell.textString sizeToFit];

    NSDate *theDate = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:DATE];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:DATE_FORMAT];
    NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];
    cell.timeLabel.text = timeString;                                       // set timeLabel to display date and time
    cell.userLabel.text = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:NAME]; // set userLabel to display userName

    self.bubbleImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.bubbleImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,22,250,CGRectGetMaxY(cell.textString.frame)+10.0);
    self.bubbleImage.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleMine.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:21 topCapHeight:14];

    [self.bubbleImage addSubview:cell.userLabel];
    [self.bubbleImage addSubview:cell.timeLabel];
    [self.bubbleImage addSubview:cell.textString];

    [cell addSubview:self.bubbleImage];
        }
return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 NSString *cellText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:TEXT];
//calculate height for each row based on the textString
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE];
CGSize size1 = [cellText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(150.0f, 1000.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
return size1.height+100.0; //or whatever padding value you need
}
```

there is problem in this :

```
CGRectGetMaxY(cell.textString.frame)+10.0
```

in line as below:

```
self.bubbleImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,22,250,CGRectGetMaxY(cell.textString.frame)+10.0);
```

because i am getting 2/3 images for single cell .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you keep adding new subviews to the cell each time they are reused. Instead of just doing:

```
[cell addSubview:self.bubbleImage];
```

Try:

```
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:self.bubbleImage];
```

A better alternative would be to create a single `UIImageView` for `bubbleImage` when the cell is created and set its autoresizing mask. Then when the cell is resized the image will automatically be changed appropriately...